# If $A$ is normal: why $\sigma(A)=\sigma_\pi(A)$ implies that $\omega(A)\geq r(A)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

I see in [this paper](https://msp.org/pjm/1981/95-1/pjm-v95-n1-p03-s.pdf) the following theorem:

[image]

The proof is not difficult. However, I don't understant the first sentence:

[image]

> I don't understant why the fact that $\sigma(A)=\sigma_\pi(A)$ implies that $\omega(A)\geq r(A)$? If $n=1$, it is well known that for every normal operators $A$, we have
>   $$\sigma(A)=\sigma_\pi(A).$$
>   Even if $n=1$, I don't see why $\sigma(A)=\sigma_\pi(A)$ implies that $\omega(A)\geq r(A)$?

Here,

[image]

and $\sigma(A)$ is defined as

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: How are $\ \omega(A)\ $ and $\ r(A)\ $ defined ?

Comment: @Peter Please see my edit. Even if $n=1$ the inequality is not clear to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z_1,\dots,z_n\in \sigma(A)$ and $\epsilon>0$. Since $\sigma(A)=\sigma_\pi(A)$, there exist a unit vector $x$ such that $\|(A_k-z_k)x\|<\epsilon$. Thus
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n|z_k|^2&=\sum_{k=1}^n|\langle z_k x,x\rangle|^2\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n|\langle(z_k-A_k)x,x\rangle+\langle A_k x,x\rangle|^2\\
&\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\left((1+\delta^{-1}) |\langle (z_k-A_k)x,x\rangle|^2+(1+\delta)|\langle A_k x,x\rangle|^2\right)\\
&\leq(1+\delta^{-1})n\epsilon^2+(1+\delta)\sum_{k=1}^n|\langle A_k x,x\rangle|^2\\
&\leq (1+\delta^{-1})n\epsilon^2+(1+\delta) w(A)^2
\end{align*}
Letting first $\epsilon\to 0$ and then $\delta\to 0$, we arrive at the desired inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please I don't understand the following inequality: \begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n|\langle z_k x,x\rangle|^2
&\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\left((1+\delta^{-1}) \langle (z_k-A_k)x,x\rangle^2+(1+\delta)\langle A_k x,x\rangle^2\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: That was probably too many steps at one (plus I forgot a bunch of absolute values). I used Young's inequality in the form $2ab\leq \delta a^2+\delta^{-1}b^2$.

Comment: Thanks. The proof is not obvious.